# Pass class as value and create Instance

Tags: scala

I have many classes of a common base trait. I have a function that needs to create a new instance of a instance of one of these classes, but which one is only known at runtime.

Is it possible to pass this class as a parameter and create an instance at runtime in Scala?

I'm not even sure that the answer would be the best approach but currently it's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the value thus:

```
myFunc(classOf[myObj])
```

to the method with signature

```
def myFunc(clazz : AnyRef)={ ...
```

but this smells bad. You're either looking at implementing a [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html), or better still you could use polymorphism and simply do:

```
myObj.myFunc
```

since your functionality is predicated on what class is involved.

Comment: I think I'll use the factory pattern (no one likes smelly code).

Answer (score 2):

Same as in Java:

```
classOf[MyClass].newInstance // calls the constructor without parameters
classOf[MyClass].getConstructor(/* parameter types */).newInstance(/* parameters */)
```

See [Javadoc for Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

This will work in any Scala version. Scala 2.10 has [new reflection libraries](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors), which are aware of Scala concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to avoid as much as you can reflection, as it can easily lead to hardly testable code and runtime exceptions.

You can, however, make a builder for that class like the following:

```
trait Builder[A]{
   def newItem:A
}
```

and then pass to your func the proper builder

```
def myFunc[A](param1:B,builder:Builder[A])
```

and you can also leverage implicits

```
def myFunc[A](param1:B)(implicit builder:Builder[A])
```

Maybe you can detail a little bit more your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally avoid reflection.

If you can identify beforehand all the possible use cases and classify them using an identifier:

```
trait SUPER

class A extends SUPER
class B extends SUPER
class C extends SUPER
class D extends SUPER

val idA = 'CLASS_A
val idB = 'CLASS_B
val idC = 'CLASS_C
val idD = 'CLASS_D

def build(selectedId: Symbol): SUPER = selectedId match {
  case 'CLASS_A => new A
  case 'CLASS_B => new B
  case 'CLASS_C => new C
  case 'CLASS_D => new D
}
```

else if you prefer builders I'd follow @Edmondo1984 's advice

Answer (score 0):

The most "seamless" way to get what you want is to declare the method that will do the instantiation as having a type parameter with a context bound of `ClassManifest`

```
def maker[T : ClassManifest](args...): T = ...
```

which will cause the compiler to automatically pass an instance of `ClassManifest[T]` to maker. The caller need only specify the particular class they want instantiated.

```
package rrs.scribble

import  scala.reflect.ClassManifest

object  Maker
{
  def maker[T : ClassManifest]: T = {
    val cmT = implicitly[ClassManifest[T]]
    val cT = cmT.runtimeClass
    cT.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

This only works when there is a no-arg constructor for the classes in question. You can invoke constructors with arguments, but it's a lot more involved. You'll have to familiarize yourself with the Java reflection API.

In the REPL:

```
scala> import rrs.scribble.Maker._
import rrs.scribble.Maker._

scala> class Argless
defined class Argless

scala> val s1 = maker[Argless]
s1: Argless = Argless@1512d075
```

Comment: I know that, but they are still available and there is a replacement, so the tactic works and as shown is portable across versions 2.8 through 2.10 (at least).